# Prove that the image of a compact set under the composition of two continuous functions is compact

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $K$ is compact and $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $(f\circ g)(K)$ (the composition of $f$ and $g$, in case that wasn't clear) is compact. What do you have to assume about the the domain and ranges of $f$ and $g$?

So what I'm thinking about this so far is to use the fact that the continuous image of a bounded set is bounded, but I'm unsure of how to apply that to a composition of two functions.

Comment: This is straightforward from the fact that if $h: X \to Y$ is continous and $K$ compact, then $h(K)$ is compact.

Comment: And the fact that the composition of two continuous functions is ....

Comment: It's definely bot true that the continuous image of a bounded set is bounded. Example $(0,1)\ni t\mapsto 1/t\in\Bbb R$. It is true, however, if you replace "bounded" by "compact".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a function $f:K\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if for any open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R},$ its pre-image $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $K.$

Also, a set $K$ is compact if for any collection of open sets $\mathcal{U} = \{ U: U \text{ is open }\}$ such that 
$$K \subseteq \bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U,$$
then there exists $\{1,2,...,n\}$ such that 
$$K\subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^n U_k.$$

**Now, we wish to prove that if $f$ is continuous on a compact set $K$, then its pre-image $f^{-1}(K)$ is also compact.**

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be any open cover for $f(K),$ that is, 
$$f(K) \subseteq \bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U.$$
Then 
$$K \subseteq f^{-1}\bigg( \bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U \bigg) = \bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}f^{-1}(U).$$
By compactness of $K,$ there exists $\{1,2,...,n \}$ such that 
$$K \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^n f^{-1}(U_k).$$
Then 
$$f(K) \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^n U_k.$$
Therefore, $f(K)$ is covered by finitely many open sets and thus $f(K)$ is compact.